# How to call PL/SQL procedure in Ibatis from java

Tags: java, plsql, ibatis

I have written a PLSQL stored procedure , i want to call the procedure and return the resultset back to the java in a hashmap or arraylist  format . I want to configure it in the xml file using Ibatis. kindly let me know how to configure in Ibatis.

Comment: http://frommyworkshop.blogspot.com/2010/04/call-plsql-package-by-ibatis-3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<procedure id="yourProc" parameterClass="yourclass" resultMap="result">
    {call yourProc(#param1#,#param2#)}
</procedure>
```